# recognize specific pattern with help of regex

Tags: python, regex, split

please help to recognize an item id from junk text. An id starts from **300** and consist of 12 digit characters.

For example:

- ЗКЗ **300000459908**  Кап. ремонт
- 3   ЗКЗ **300000459908**  печи №15
- USER4
- 4   OR**300000459908**   Кап. ремонт короткой
- OR**30000045990**

Thank you!

Comment: You can use `\b300\d{9}\b`

Answer (score 4):

Will find all ids from text and returns a list of them.

```
import re

text = """
For example: ЗКЗ 300000459908 Кап. ремонт 3 ЗКЗ 300000459908 печи №15
USER4 4 OR300000459908 Кап. ремонт короткой OR30000045990

ids = re.findall(r'300\d{9}', text)
print(ids)
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple one : /300[0-9]{9}/ .